# In AngularJS how do I pass variables between controllers with a service?

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass a variable between controllers with a service. Here is the service to pass the variable (in this case a song id):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('PortalApp')
  .service('ActionbarService', ['$window', function ActionbarService(window) {
    var song;
    return {
        getSong: function () {
            return song;
        },
        setSong: function(value) {
            song = value;
        }
    };
  }]);
```

Here is the relevant part of the controller I am setting the song from:

```
$scope.actionbarSetSong = function(song_id) {
  ActionbarService.setSong(song_id);
}
```

and here is the controller I am getting the song id from:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('PortalApp')
  .controller('ActionbarCtrl', function ($scope, MediaService, ActionbarService, $location, $routeParams, AudioPlayerAPI) {
    $scope.song_id = ActionbarService.getSong();
    $scope.openPlaylistModal = function (song_id) {

      $("#addToPlaylist").modal('show');
    }
  });
```

It is being set in the service because when I do getSong in my view it worked (I forget where), but then when I try to set it in my 2nd controller it doesn't work. Here's the relevant part of my view for reference:

```
    <div class="cell action-bar" ng-click="actionbarSetSong(song.id);" ng-repeat="song in media.data">
Some Stuff
    </div>
```

Comment: Can't you just set the value in $rootScope?  Then you wouldn't need the service.

Comment: Make sure both controllers are on the same page.

Comment: where is your `player`? `data-ng-click="player.setSong(song.id);"`

Comment: Sorry, that was another similarly-named thing. To be honest, I forget where we got player from.

Comment: Both controllers are on the same "page," but I'm not sure they're in the same scope. I think either one is a child of the other or both are the children of another scope. Sometimes it's hard to tell with Angular.

Comment: All scopes are children of the $rootScope. You can inject and use it in any controller, service, factory or directive. Also, because of prototypal inheritance, any values added to the $rootScope are accessible via the child scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmm.. service returns `new ActionbarService`. You probably want to use `factory`, or change your getters/setters to `this.get` & `this.set`.

Also, avoid polluting the `$rootScope`; whenever you want to share data between controllers, use a [service](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers).

Comment: Yes, there was another Stack answer on that (well, at least one), but it doesn't seem like good coding practice. I will look into using factories.

Comment: Sorry, I meant using $rootScope doesn't seem like good coding practice. Angular services seem fine, although strange and magical, like everything Angular.

Comment: Give it some time, it gets better :)